# Finding and printing the lowest value number and its indexes from a newly generated matrix

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I want to read and print A matrix from a txt file, then create a new matrix B whose elements are the average of the row and column from A matrix, and then find the lowest valued number in the B matrix, print it and print its indexes.
If the element "1" is the lowest and it is in the 2nd row and 3rd column, there should be printed below the matrix B "The lowest element is 1 with indexes 2;3".

For example the element B23 should be the average of the sum of the elements of row 2 and column 3 of matrix A.

The input for the A matrix is coming from a txt file, where on the first row are m and n (rows and columns) and below them is the actual matirx.

Example input:

```
3 3
2 9 8
4 2 5
5 2 3
```

Expected answer:

```
Matrix A        
2.00    9.00    8.00
4.00    2.00    5.00
5.00    2.00    3.00
Matrix B
15.00   16.00   17.50
11.00   12.00   13.50
10.50   11.50   13.00
```

The lowest element is 10.50 with indexes 3,1.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Matrix()

    Dim m As Integer, n As Integer, A() As Single, _
        MaxA As Single, r_Max As Integer

    Call InputMatrix(m, n, A)
    Call NewMatrixB(A, m)
 
End Sub


Sub InputMatrix(m As Integer, n As Integer, A() As Single)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim FName As String

    FName = InputBox("Vuvedete ime na fail s vhodni danni", _
        "matrix", "H:\School\matrix.txt")
 
    If Dir(FName) = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Failut " & FName & " ne e nameren!")
        Stop
 
    End If

    Close #1
 
    Open FName For Input As #1
    Input #1, m, n
    ReDim A(m, n)
    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            Input #1, A(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Close #1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells.Clear
    Call OutMatrix(m, n, A, 1, "Matrix A")

End Sub


Sub OutMatrix(m As Integer, n As Integer, A() As Single, _
    r As Integer, title As String)

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    With Cells(r, 1)
        .Value = title
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            Cells(r + i, j).Value = A(i, j)
            Cells(r + i, j).NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Sub NewMatrixB(Data As Variant, m As Integer)

    Dim X As Variant
    X = Data
    
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim numCols As Long
    
    numRows = UBound(X, 1)
    numCols = UBound(X, 2)
    
    ReDim rowSum(1 To numCols) As Double
    ReDim colSum(1 To numRows) As Double
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = 1 To numRows
        For c = 1 To numCols
            rowSum(c) = rowSum(c) + X(r, c)
            colSum(r) = colSum(r) + X(r, c)
        Next
    Next
   
    ReDim B(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols) As Double
    For r = 1 To numRows
        For c = 1 To numCols
            B(r, c) = (rowSum(c) + colSum(r)) / 2
        Next
    Next
    
    With Cells(m + 3, 1)
        .Value = "Matrix B"
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
           
    End With
    
    Cells(m + 4, 1).Resize(numRows, numCols) = B
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:X100").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    Dim Min As Integer
   
End Sub


Sub Minimum(m As Integer, Matrixxx As Single)

    MsgBox Application.Min(Matrixxx)

End Sub
```

My code is up to the new matrix B and printing it.
How do I find the new one and make it a type, where I can get the indexes as well?
I also have trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Not a very good question as you miss out some important details.  Please give an example of the structure of the file you need to read.  Its not clear by what you mean by ' average of the row and column from A matrix' so please provide a small matric and an example of the result you expect to get from that matrix.  As an aside if you have an m x n matric x where m<>n you will have some difficulty in constructing a matrix with only values that are either a average of a column or an average of a row.

Comment: I edited and added an example. The average means that element B11 is the average of the sum of row 1 and column 1 of matrix A. I managed to do it and there is no problem with creating the B matrix, but I cant get the Matrix B, find the lowest element and the indexes and print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return a value then define a function. To return more than one value use an array.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Process_Matrix()

    ' define matrices
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
    
    A = InputMatrix("matrix.txt") '"H:\School\matrix.txt")
    Call OutMatrix("Matrix A", Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), A)
    
    B = NewMatrixB(A)
    Call OutMatrix("Matrix B", Sheet1.Cells(12, 1), B)

    Dim idx, msg As String
    idx = getMin(B)
    msg = "Min = " & B(idx(0), idx(1)) & " at B(" & idx(0) & "," & idx(1) & ")"
    
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation
 
End Sub

Function getMin(ByRef X) As Variant

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Double, ar(0 To 1) As Long
    m = X(1, 1)
    ar(0) = 1
    ar(1) = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(X)
        For j = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
            If X(i, j) < m Then
                m = X(i, j)
                ar(0) = i
                ar(1) = j
            End If
        Next
    Next
    getMin = ar
End Function


Function InputMatrix(Fname As String) As Variant
         
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long, A() As Single
    Fname = InputBox("Vuvedete ime na fail s vhodni danni", _
    "matrix", Fname)
     
    If Dir(Fname) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Failut " & Fname & " ne e nameren!", vbCritical
        Stop
     
    End If
    Close #1
     
    Open Fname For Input As #1
    Input #1, m, n
    
    ReDim A(1 To m, 1 To n)
    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            Input #1, A(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
    InputMatrix = A
      
End Function
    
Sub OutMatrix(title As String, rng As Range, ByRef X)
    
    With rng
        .Value = title
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(X), UBound(X, 2))
            .Value = X
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
    End With
     
End Sub
     
Function NewMatrixB(ByRef X) As Variant
    
    Dim B, rowSum, colSum
    Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    numRows = UBound(X, 1)
    numCols = UBound(X, 2)
    ReDim rowSum(1 To numRows) As Double
    ReDim colSum(1 To numCols) As Double
        
    For r = 1 To numRows
        For c = 1 To numCols
            rowSum(c) = rowSum(c) + X(r, c)
            colSum(r) = colSum(r) + X(r, c)
        Next
    Next
            
    ReDim B(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols) As Double
    For r = 1 To numRows
        For c = 1 To numCols
            B(r, c) = (rowSum(c) + colSum(r)) / 2
        Next
    Next
    NewMatrixB = B
       
End Function
```